# Can I bypass these two adapters?

Tags: power-supply, power, inverter, adapter, plug

**Scenario**

I have a `LiPo` battery connected to a **DC** > **AC** inverter and these two adapters (images below) are plugged into the inverter.

**Hypothesis**

Everything runs fine currently but I know I'm losing juice in the conversion back and forth. Cutting out the **DC** > **AC** inverter, **AC** > **DC** adapters, and running power straight from the `~12v` battery to the `12v` devices should work.

**Question**

The LiPo fluctuates from `12.6v` *(full charge)* to  `9v` but my shut-off alarm is set to `9.9v`. Are there any caveats here? The first adapter from "FSP Group Inc." is for an "Nvidia Jetson TK1" computer so I'd hate to fry that.

**Extra**

What is the name of the plug on the "FSP Group Inc adapter"? I'd like to buy a separate one instead of cutting that one off the adapter.

***LiPo Specs***

- 11.1v
- 6500 mAh
- 20C

[image: nvidia jetson tk1 power adapter]
[image: kinect powered usb adapter]

## Edit - Power Consumption

**Jetson TK1 Power Consumption** *[link](http://elinux.org/Jetson/Jetson_TK1_Power)*

- Booting up: ~3.6W (for ~2 minutes booting)
- CLI via SSH: ~1.6W
- Heavy Disk Usage: 1.6W - 4.7W
- Input Range: **9.5v - 13.5v**

**Microsoft Kinect Power Consumption** *[link](https://www.engadget.com/2010/11/04/kinect-teardown-two-cameras-four-microphones-12-watts-of-powe/)*

- 12 watts
- Input Range: **8.5v** (~0.42A) - **12v** (~0.35A) *[link](http://www.kinecthesia.com/2011/04/kinect-minimum-voltage.html)*

I'm surprised to see that the kinect requires so much more than the computer.

Comment: So to understand if the loads are ok with the setup you describe you'll need to add info about the loads and their acceptable input supply ranges.

Comment: I found information regarding device power consumption. As for acceptable input supply ranges I'm not sure how to find that out. Everything I found I added to the bottom of my question.

Comment: suggest reviewing the link you posted above for the jetson tk1, esp http://elinux.org/Jetson/Jetson_TK1_Power#Powering_the_Jetson_TK1_board_with_a_battery  The link shows the acceptable input voltage range.

Comment: It appears I was too hasty, I appreciate you pointing that out. Now that I know the terms to search for I was able to find out more about the Kinect input ranges as well. I've added the results.

Comment: The Kinect has motors in it, of course it will be more than a solid state computer designed for low power mobile platforms.

Comment: The other option would be to use a dc to DC boost converter. Less power loss than the inverter setup.

Comment: @Passerby I unplugged the dc motor on the Kinect so hopefully that will help with conservation. I like this boost converter idea, this is the first I've heard of that (I'm new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I can

- LiPo 11.1V DC (12.6V-9.0V) to
- DC/DC Boost Converter Step-up Voltage Transformer 3-34V to 4-35V 6A Volt Regulator Controller (set to 12V DC output) to
- - Male DC Power Pigtail Plug to Computer (Jetson TK1)
- - I cut off the "DC connector" from the AC adapter for the Kinect's powered USB cable and connected + - of exposed wires direct Step-up Converter.

***Note:*** I couldn't get the Kinect to have sufficient power when going through the transformer so I left the computer on the transformer and connected the Kinect straight to the LiPo since [the Kinect supports ~9V-13V DC](http://www.kinecthesia.com/2011/04/kinect-minimum-voltage.html)